# Java - Generate random user name If the user doesn't enter input

Tags: java, if-statement, random

Very new to coding and starting off with Java.

I am trying to create a scenario Where a user Is creating a Username and password.
I need the program to accept the users input for username and password. If the user does not enter a username or password then I need the program to generate a random username and a random number for password.

I have tried searching on google and youtube however I have had no success so far with either.

Comment: Checkout [Random UUID](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html#randomUUID()) for username and and `Random#nextInt` [nexInt](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt--) for password.

Answer (score 0):

How about going with something like this? As @Nishant suggested going with UUID class does solve your problem. Here's a sample code :

```
import java.util.UUID;
import java.util.Random;
class Test {
    //username and password are provided as command line arguments
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String uname = "";
        long pwd = -1;
        switch (args.length) { //check if agruments are provided
            case 0:
                {
                    //get a random ID and convert it to String
                    uname = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
                    pwd = new Random().nextLong();
                    break;
                }
            case 1:
                {
                    //Use the provided ID but generate a Random Password
                    uname = args[0];
                    pwd = new Random().nextLong();
                    break;
                }
            case 2:
                {
                    uname = args[0];
                    pwd = Long.parseLong(args[1]);
                    break;
                }
        }
        System.out.println("Username " + uname + " : Password " + pwd);
    }
}
```

Output would be something like this:
[image: Output after command Line arguments]
Lemme know if this solves your issue. Cheers!